# Python problem with libraries. I got some error

Tags: python, pip, artificial-intelligence

I was trying to download `imageai` using `pip` module and I got following error:

```
ERROR: tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 has requirement keras<2.12,>=2.11.0, but you'll have keras 2.4.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 has requirement numpy>=1.20, but you'll have numpy 1.19.3 which is incompatible.
```

I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Install keras version 2.11 or newer and numpy 1.20 or newer. You can use pip install command for that.

Comment: nadjagv but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are seeing indicates that the current version of TensorFlow that you have installed (`tensorflow-intel 2.11.0`) requires different versions of Keras and Numpy than the versions that are currently installed on your system. Specifically, `tensorflow-intel 2.11.0` requires Keras version less than `2.12` but you have version `2.4.3` installed, and it also requires Numpy version greater than or equal to `1.20`, but you have version `1.19.3` installed.

You could try upgrading Keras and Numpy to meet these requirements:

```
pip install keras==2.11.0
pip install numpy>=1.20
```